# Finding latitude & longitude values for both ends of a road

Tags: latitude-longitude

I am looking for a way to find latitude and longitude values of both ends of any given road. So for example if there was a site or tool that did this, I would just have to provide a road name (and maybe post/zip code) and it would give me the latitude and longitude values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no other way to approach this than using GIS software. What you are describing is the guts of what GIS is. Unless you are lucky enough to discover that someone else has done this exact thing at the same place you are requiring, this is something that has to be built from scratch.

Comment: Could you recommend any GIS software that would be good for a beginner?

Comment: The most widely used is ESRI ArcGIS, but it is not inexpensive (however if you are a student it is free at many institutions). Others are IDRISI, GRASS and qGIS. None of these are "easy", they all take time to learn. Learning this will be far slower than just using the approach you are already taking if you are starting from scratch with GIS.

what do you need this information (in your original question) for?

Answer (score 0):

Manually, using Google Maps you can right click "What's Here" on any location (start/end points of given road) and it will give you decimal degree lat/long values.

If you have access to GIS software and datasets there are faster ways to get multiple values for multiple streets

Comment: Yes I have already been using the "What's Here" option on Google Maps but it will take way long because I am trying to get these values for all the roads in a city.

Comment: Do you have GIS software and a roads dataset?

Comment: Nope, i'm not familiar with any GIS software and I don't have a clue about datasets (hehe).